# Aggregate not returning results, with user authentication in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication, pymongo

[image]
The issue I'm having, I cant make the aggregate search work. I have been able to run it in a mongodb without any users, however in the mongodb with users (even when authentication is not turned on) i get this weird error message (see below). Whats weirder is I have no problem with other functions for example find().count() witch as you can see below returns 32 (the number of results in the database).

Code in MongoDB shell to create user.

```
 use admin    

db.createUser( { user: "VibrationDataCollector",
                pwd: '45.',
                roles: [ "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                        "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                                "clusterAdmin" ] } )
```

Code in python to conduct search

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://xx.x.x.xx:xxxxx/')
db = client['VibrationDataDB']
db.authenticate('VibrationDataCollector', '45.', source='admin')
coll = db.VibrationData

hello = coll.find().count()
print 'count=', hello


LastWrite_Time = coll.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$Records"
}, {
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [{
                "$anyElementTrue": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$Records.Properties",
                        "as": "result",
                        "in": {
                            "$and": [{
                                "$eq": ["$$result.Property.Name", "LastWrite_User"]
                            }, {
                                "$eq": ["$$result.value", "42"]
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Records.Properties"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "Records.Properties.Property.Name": 'LastWrite_Time'
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "value": "$Records.Properties.value"
    }
}])



list1 = LastWrite_Time['result']
for T in list1:
        print T['value']
```

Result

```
count= 32

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python_scripts/SimulationCEI.py", line 64, in <module>
    list1 = LastWrite_Time['result']
TypeError: 'CommandCursor' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

UPDATEEEEE!!!!

using next()

```
count= 32

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python_scripts/SimulationCEI.py", line 64, in <module>
    list1 = LastWrite_Time['result']
TypeError: 'CommandCursor' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> next()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    next()
TypeError: next expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
>>>
```

Comment: `aggregate()` returns [`CommandCursor`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) not a dict. Advance thru the cursor using `next()` to fetch the data.

Comment: @franklinsijo
i was using

for x in list1:
      print x['value']

but still get the same result

Comment: I do not see that in the code or in the error!

Comment: sorry will put it back in. Guess i cut it off to early

Comment: made a quick update as to what happens when using next() in the shell after running the code, including the print for loop

Comment: You can try to loop throught `LastWrite_Time` and get the value of `result` key if it exists in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
for T in LastWrite_Time:
    print T['value']
```

"aggregate" returns a cursor that must be iterated. I'm certain that authentication is not related to the error you see.

Comment: this is what i originally had, it wasnt working. then I made the loop with

for T in list1:
    list1.next()
    print T['value']

and it started working, then i deleted the list1.next() and its still working. Im super confused.